# GridView isn't being displayed correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I took a screenshot of it. Its displaying some weird way:
[image]

This is the code.

The GridAdapter:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Uri> mUrls;  
// references to our images

public GridViewAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Uri> images) {
    mContext = c;
    this.mUrls = images;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mUrls.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ImageView inflatedImageView = (ImageView) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview_amb_background, null);

    //ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

    inflatedImageView.setImageURI(mUrls.get(position));

    inflatedImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

    return inflatedImageView;
}
```

And the `inflatedImageView` is a layout inflate, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bgimages" 
    android:maxWidth="120dp"
    android:padding="5dp">

</ImageView>
```

On the other hand, I've a gridView in a xml file:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="250dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
android:numColumns="3"
android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
</GridView>
```

So, I inflate this gridView, I add several URI's (3 exactly) in a loop. Once added, I set the adapter to the gridview:

```
ArrayList<Uri> uriFotos = new ArrayList<Uri>();
HashMap<Integer, ListItem> items = xmlList.getItems();
for (int i = 0; i<items.size();i++){
     ListItem itemActual = items.get(i);
     itemActual.getLogoSrc();
     uriFotos.add(Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+rutaFinsCarpetaClient+itemActual.getLogoSrc()));
 }
 gridViewInflated.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(this,uriFotos));
variableContent.addView(gridViewInflated);
```

The images are "linked" correctly.

`variableContent` is a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView, so the grid should be scrollable.
But as you can see few things are happening:

- Height is soo big. Shouldn't it be like the `inflatedImageView` says?
- *Scroll isnt working. Well, its working but i've to move the finger around and tap several times until it works. If i stop scrolling I've to repeat the same proces until it reacts again.* (SOLVED)

Hope you guys can help me. I've changed lots of layouts, changed widths, heights, and the same thing is happening.

Note that the image you see that is in the gridView, is something like 1200x800px.

**Edit**
The same code with smaller images:

[image]

Comment: remove background image for imageview and set as android:src from the xml

Comment: Have you tried settings the GridView column height to android:layout_height="wrap_content"?

Comment: @vsk I can't do that. Background is a background for the whole view, then dinamically I add a image on SRC from a jpg file in the sdcard. So I've to have both: bg and src. Btw, this bg is 162x162. White. With border around it.

Comment: @user2045570 yes, I did. I also have set the gridview to a static number like 700dp, and the same thing is happening. Seems to be cut.

Comment: Be aware that you shouldn't have the GridView in a ScrollableLayout since the GridView itself is scrollable.  src :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

Comment: Oh. @Guian Didn't remember. Going to see what can I do there. Will post results.

Comment: @Guian OK. This solved the issue with scrolling. 1 of 2 done! Now we've to find out why are the images displayed this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to set the Image view size to wrap_content :

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and if you really need the 120dp height, try to reset this size after having set the image src:

```
 inflatedImageView.setImageURI(mUrls.get(position));

 inflatedImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(120, 120));
```

also set the scaleType before adding the picture (preferably in the xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:background="@drawable/bgimages" 
    android:maxWidth="120dp"
    android:padding="5dp">

</ImageView>
```

Comment: Applied each of your tips, and finally its being shown somehow correctly, but there's too much space between each image. Check this picture: http://i.imgur.com/KdLiUOg.png (EDIT) nvm, I've set maxColumns to 3 and the space is smaller. I'll have to do some adjusts. Thats all. Thanks man.<3